# Select all distinct values where datestamp is in the last 24 hours and order by total rows ASC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct, unix-timestamp

I have a query I am trying to formulate, but it keeps giving me unexpected results.

What I need to do is:

select all distinct values from my table where the unix timestamp is >= the last 24 hours, then order these results by which one has the highest amount of entries.

I have managed the time part:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) as myValue from table_name WHERE time_column >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This works as expected. Then I was just going to use PHP to sort through the results etc etc, however I wish to use the power of SQL on this one.

Any ideas how I can extend the above query to encapsulate counting the amount of distinct column_name values? Also to then sort this in order dependent on how many values are in each one?

So essentially I want to get my results like so :

```
a unique ID  | highest amount
a unique ID  | second highest amount
a unique ID  | lowest amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, and in my case it works perfectly:

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) as myValue
FROM table_name
WHERE time_column >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY myValue DESC
```

This gave me the 3 values which I expected. Which were the 3 values in the last 24 hours, and they were ordered by the amount of occurrences of this were in the database table - I tested this by manually creating another occurrence of these and checking at each stage. Worked a treat

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `group by` for this query:

```
SELECT column_name as myValue, count(*) as cnt
from table_name
WHERE time_column >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried your way but ordering by count(*) did not do anything - it gave me a syntax error if anything. So I moved this around and provided my own answer also, which seemed to work for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction of GROUP BY

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @steve-king . . . Strange behavior.  MySQL allows the `count(*)` in the `order by` without having a variable:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/46907.